# What does the /= operator in C# do?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, division

What does the /= operator in C# do and when is it used?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's divide-and-assign.  `x /= n` is logically equivalent to `x = x / n`.

Comment: ... except that `x` is only evaluated once (which is observable if it is an expression with side effects - e.g., a chain of property gets).

Comment: Excellent illustration of the difference between logical equivalence and practical equivalence. :)

Answer (score 7):

It is similar to `+=`, `-=` or `*=`. It's a shortcut for a mathematical division operation with an assignment.  Instead of doing

```
x = x / 10;
```

You can get the same result by doing

```
x /= 10;
```

It assigns the result to the original variable after the operation has taken place.

Comment: @Asmodon
You are wrong. Both of womps lines are equivalent. And they both modify the value of x (the same way). AND it is shorter, if only by an 'x' and a space ;)

Answer (score 4):

In most languages inspired by C, the answer is: divide and assign.  That is:

```
a /= b;
```

is a short-hand for:

```
a = a / b;
```

The LHS (`a` in my example) is evaluated once.  This matters when the LHS is complex, such as an element from an array of structures:

```
x[i].pqr /= 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

`a /= 2;` is the same of `a = a / 2;`.

Answer (score 2):

A division and an assignment:

```
a /= b;
```

is the same as

```
a = (a / b);
```

Its simply a combination of the two operators into one.

Answer (score 2):

In the following example:

```
double value = 10;
value /= 2;
```

Value will have a final value of 5.

The =/ operator divides the variable by the operand (in this case, 2) and stores the result back in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
a /= b;
```

is the same as

```
a = a / b;
```

Here's the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d31sybc9(VS.71).aspx) on the operator.